# ¿Como recorro una serie de hash dentro de un array y verificar su contenido?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow.

Tengo mi siguiente duda en rails tengo el siguiente hash dentro de un array. `@permissions_crud_hash = [:name => name_, :c => c, :r => r, :u => u, :d => d]
@permissions_crud.push @permissions_crud_hash`
que tiene como ejemplo  un valor algo así.

```
[{:name=>["Administracion"], :c=>[true], :r=>[true], :u=>[false], :d=>[false]}], [{:name=>["Permisos"], :c=>[true], :r=>[true], :u=>[true], :d=>[true]}]]
```

Lo que deseo saber es como saco de ese hash cada valor ejemplo quiero sacar si existe el nombre de "Permisos" dentro de ese hash y cada valor como por ejemplo, c, r, u, d.

un ejemplo que intento hacer pero no me da es este.

```
      if @permissions_crud.include?(['Permisos'])

      if `@permissions_crud.include?(['Permisos'][:c=>true])`
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer tu arreglo está más *anidado* de lo que debería y, para que sea un arreglo válido, hace falta un `[`, por lo que el arreglo se vería así:

```
[
    [{:name=>["Administracion"], :c=>[true], :r=>[true], :u=>[false], :d=>[false]}],
    [{:name=>["Permisos"], :c=>[true], :r=>[true], :u=>[true], :d=>[true]}]
]
```

Considerando esa estructura, podrías obtener el valor utilizando primero `flatten` para quitar la *capa extra* del arreglo (i.e. convertirlo en un arreglo de *hashes* en lugar de un arreglo de *arreglos*) y después utilizar `find`; por ejemplo:

```
permisos = @permissions_crud.flatten.find { |p| p[:name] == ["Permisos"] }
#=> {:name=>["Permisos"],:c=>[true],:r=>[true],:u=>[true],:d=>[true]}
```

Y para obtener cada valor, simplemente consulta la llave que buscas directamente en el *hash* que acabas de obtener; por ejemplo:

```
permisos[:c]
#=> [true]
```

Si tienes control sobre el arreglo  te recomendaría simplificarlo quitando todas las *capas extras* las cuales parecen innecesarias, dejando tu estructura más simple:

```
[
    { :name=>"Administracion", :c=>true, :r=>true, :u=>false, :d=>false }, 
    { :name=>"Permisos", :c=>true, :r=>true, :u=>true, :d=>true }
]
```

Para obtener los valores el proceso sería prácticamente igual, pero sin `flatten` y con el beneficio de obtener el valor final en lugar de un arreglo (e. `true` en lugar de `[true]`):

```
permisos = @permissions_crud.find { |p| p[:name] == "Permisos" }
#=> {:name=>"Permisos",:c=>true,:r=>true,:u=>true,:d=>true}

permisos[:c]
#=> true
```